# gem install capistrano failure

Tags: installation, rubygems

I tried to install the package "capistrano" on a linux box but got the following error:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/bin/ruby terminated
```

Additionally it showed me a list of the memory map and then the install process was aborted.

Any idea on what causes this error?

Cheers
Roland

Comment: I used the following command to install the package:                                                              gem install capistrano

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue when installing Capistrano on CentOs 6.7, Ruby 1.8.5, gem 1.3.1. Turns out the issue was caused by newest highline package.

The following allowed me to install capistrano correctly:

```
    gem install highline --version "=1.6.2"
    gem install capistrano --version "=2.6.0"
```

Comment: I tried to install highline versions `1.6.11` (current version as of Feb 7 2012) all the way down to `1.6.5` and they all encounter buffer overflows with the following setup [`CentOS 5.7`, `Ruby 1.8.5`, `Gem 1.3.1`]. Versions `1.6.3` and `1.6.4` appear not to have been released.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be related to some Ruby 1.8.6 bugs (see this post http://opsrealism.tumblr.com/post/4931621276/mirroring-rubygems-and-ruby-9-2-on-centos-5-5 for some more details), so you may try to upgrade your Ruby to 1.8.7, if it's possible.

Another option is to try to install a bit older version of gem - it worked for me on a couple of occasions, where exact gem versions didn't matter. For example,

> gem install capistrano --version "=2.7.0"

might work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Problem is I cannot upgrade to an older/never ruby gem version as my environment needs to reflect the production one, in which, to my surprise, there was no problem with executing the gem install command. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm running:

- Centos 5.5
- Ruby 1.8.5
- Gems 1.3.1

I narrowed the problem down to the highline gem. Although I attempted to intall all of its dependencies manually (which worked), it still failed to load itself unless I followed the above advice and specified the version, 1.6.2.  =(

```
gem install highline --version "=1.6.2"
```

Hopefully, I'll be migrating off of this ancient OS soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues installing `cap` for CentOS 5.8 but it worked using the rvm installer (to upgrade to latest ruby, I used `1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]`)

What I d

1. I `yum remove ruby` (to get rid of 1.8.x)
2. I followed simple instructions at https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ for installing rvm
3. gem install capistrano
4. `cap` command is found!

Hope this helps someones